# Redundant bonus spells for cleric peace domain

Tags: dnd-5e, spellcasting, cleric

At first level, peace clerics gain heroism and sanctuary. But don't all clerics already have access to all cleric spells (at the appropriate levels), which includes sanctuary? Only wizards, warlock, sorcerers and rangers have access to a limited number of spells.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

#### Domain Spells are always prepared and don’t count against your total prepared spells.

The [rules for Domain Spells](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/cleric#DivineDomain-109) state:

> Each domain has a list of spells — its domain spells — that you gain at the cleric levels noted in the domain description. *Once you gain a domain spell, you always have it prepared, and it doesn’t count against the number of spells you can prepare each day.*

So yes, *sanctuary* is already on the cleric spell list, but a Peace cleric has it prepared without it counting against their total prepared spells since it is one of their domain spells. Other clerics have to prepare *sanctuary* as usual, Peace clerics do not.

This phenomenon is not unique to the Peace domain. The chief offender is the Life domain: *every single one of their domain spells is already a cleric spell*. So the Life domain doesn't get any new spells at all.

Comment: It may also be worth pointing out that it is not unique to clerics either, eg. a Forest druid will get barkskin as a Circle spell. The subclass spells feature for Warlocks is different though.